# Tableau-cluster-linux Cloudformation template failing while creating bastion autoscaling group

Tags: aws-cloudformation, tableau-api

> The following resource(s) failed to create: [BastionAutoScalingGroup].

BastionAutoScalingGroup CREATE_FAILED   Received 1 FAILURE signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement

> log from bastionHost:-

grep -ni 'error\|failure' $(sudo find /var/log -name cfn* -or -name cloud-init*)
/var/log/cloud-init.log:458:Apr 22 08:19:08 cloud-init[3012]: main.py[DEBUG]: Ran 13 modules with 0 failures
/var/log/cloud-init.log:560:Apr 22 08:19:19 cloud-init[3208]: main.py[DEBUG]: Ran 10 modules with 0 failures
/var/log/cloud-init.log:594:ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
/var/log/cloud-init.log:615:RuntimeError: Runparts: 1 failures in 1 attempted commands
/var/log/cloud-init.log:651:Apr 22 08:20:09 cloud-init[3415]: main.py[DEBUG]: Ran 9 modules with 1 failures
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:212:--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: perl-Git-2.23.1-1.amzn2.0.2.noarch
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:215:---> Package perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17020-2.amzn2 will be installed
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:230: perl-Error           noarch     1:0.17020-2.amzn2         amzn2-core      32 k
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:249:  Installing : 1:perl-Error-0.17020-2.amzn2.noarch                          3/8
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:261:  Verifying  : 1:perl-Error-0.17020-2.amzn2.noarch                          7/8
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:272:  perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17020-2.amzn2
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:842:Error occurred during build: Command b-bootstrap failed
/var/log/cfn-init.log:20:2020-04-22 08:20:08,653 [ERROR] Command b-bootstrap (./bastion_bootstrap.sh --banner https://aws-quickstart.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/quickstart-linux-bastion/scripts/banner_message.txt --enable false --tcp-forwarding false --x11-forwarding false) failed
/var/log/cfn-init.log:35:2020-04-22 08:20:08,654 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of config: Command b-bootstrap failed
/var/log/cfn-init.log:42:    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
/var/log/cfn-init.log:43:ToolError: Command b-bootstrap failed
/var/log/cfn-init.log:44:2020-04-22 08:20:08,656 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
/var/log/cfn-init.log:45:2020-04-22 08:20:08,660 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command b-bootstrap failed
/var/log/cfn-init.log:58:    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
/var/log/cfn-init.log:59:ToolError: Command b-bootstrap failed
/var/log/cfn-init.log:61:2020-04-22 08:20:08,882 [DEBUG] Signaling resource BastionAutoScalingGroup in stack Tableau-ubuntu-BastionHost-1FMT6T80AVICN with unique ID i-0ba02ad1171cdc569 and status FAILURE
/var/log/cfn-wire.log:3:2020-04-22 08:20:08,938 [DEBUG] Response: 200 https://cloudformation.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?Status=FAILURE&ContentType=JSON&StackName=Tableau-ubuntu-BastionHost-1FMT6T80AVICN&Version=2010-05-15&UniqueId=i-0ba02ad1171cdc569&Action=SignalResource&LogicalResourceId=BastionAutoScalingGroup [headers: {'x-amzn-requestid': '9a5ea98d-c6bb-49c9-a6d1-0b663848c9f3', 'date': 'Wed, 22 Apr 2020 08:20:08 GMT', 'content-length': '100', 'content-type': 'application/json'}]
/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log:23:2020-04-22 08:20:08,653 P12339 [ERROR] Exited with error code 6

> logs from primary:-

grep -ni 'error\|failure' $(sudo find /var/log -name cfn* -or -name cloud-init*)
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2099:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2113:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2127:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2141:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2155:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2169:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2183:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2197:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2211:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2225:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2239:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2254:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2268:There are 1 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2281:There are 2 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2305:There are 3 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2475:There are 3 topology validation errors/warnings.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2485:Error: This configuration is invalid. Configuring Backgrounder node roles for
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:2496:Error: This configuration is invalid. Configuring Backgrounder node roles for
/var/log/cloud-init.log:856:2020-04-22 08:18:10,148 - main.py[DEBUG]: Ran 15 modules with 0 failures
/var/log/cloud-init.log:981:2020-04-22 08:18:23,213 - main.py[DEBUG]: Ran 14 modules with 0 failures
/var/log/cloud-init.log:1078:cloudinit.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
/var/log/cloud-init.log:1105:RuntimeError: Runparts: 1 failures in 1 attempted commands
/var/log/cloud-init.log:1141:2020-04-22 08:39:47,298 - main.py[DEBUG]: Ran 20 modules with 1 failures

Comment: You may have more luck by creating issue directly with tableau at their [github page](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-tableau-server/issues)